# Recommended way to configure max_prepared_transactions in Postgres on Kubernetes

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

What is the simplest way to configure parameter max_prepared_transactions=100 in docker kubernetes?

I am using image:

https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/

Which has postgresql.conf file at /var/lib/postgresql/data

In my kubernetes deployment, that directory is externally mounted so I can't copy postgresql.conf using Dockerfile so I need to specify that parameter as a ENV parameter in Kubernetes .yml file, or changing the location of postgresql.conf file to, for example, /etc/postgresql.conf (how can I do this as a ENV parameter too?)

Thanks

Comment: The PostgreSQL way would be to

    `ALTER SYSTEM SET max_prepared_xacts = 100`

though you'd then need to arrange for PostgreSQL to restart which might not be easy in your containermajiggy.

Comment: Yes, I want to pre-configure it so any new instance of my container will already have that property set without having to execute that SQL command.

Answer (score 7):

You can set this config as runtime flag when you start your docker container. Something like this:

```
$ docker run -d postgres --max_prepared_transactions=100
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the [Postgres chart from Bitnami](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/postgresql), you can add this to your `values.yaml`.

```yaml
  postgresqlExtendedConf:
    { "maxPreparedTransactions" : 100 }
```